# What are the possible health issues caused by Maggie Noodles? What steps can be taken to minimize the aftereffects?

Tags: nutrition, chemical

Recently Nestle's Maggie Noodles was in news headlines and banned in India. It is said that the food crossed the permitted limits of chemicals such as monosodium glutamate, lead, etc.

So what are all the aftereffects on people who were using this for a few of these years? What steps can be taken to  minimize the damages or aftereffects?

Comment: Isn't monosodium glutamate safe?

Comment: see this question, https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/what-are-the-health-risks-associated-with-monosodium-glutamate-if-any

Comment: I don't see anything valuable there

Comment: We may need to wait for the right answer for that question. BTW, MSG(AKA Ajinamotto) is banned in different countries as it is unsafe.

Comment: That it's banned it's not a good answer, even if it were true (for what's its worth, it hasn't been banned in any country.) Linking it to obesity because it makes food taste better is as meaningful as saying that cinnamon leads to obesity because *them rolls are yummy.* High sodium content can be found on *salt*, also not banned. I have yet to see a good, meaningful study saying it's dangerous when eaten in normal consumption levels (of course it can be dangerous, you could drown if you fall into a pool filled with it.)

Comment: By the way, leaving MSG aside, lead ingestion is a serious issue. Perhaps that's a better question?

Comment: I have specified in the question that it had crossed the permissible levels and it is the reason for banning the noodles.