# What are the health risks associated with Monosodium Glutamate, if any?

Tags: nutrition, cancer

I've heard that it can cause cancer, but are there any studies that support this claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There several concerns related to MSG (monosodium glutamate):

- it contains **sodium**, so it might rise the blood pressure leading to **hypertension**, a risk factor of cardiovascular diseases. ([1](http://www.who.int/dietphysicalactivity/publications/trs916/en/))
- it has been found to be strictly related to **overweight and obesity** ([2](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/93/6/1328.short)), possibly because it improves the palatability of food (= it makes you feel you like it, and you want more) ([3](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031938407005021))
- in relation to **cancer**, I couldn't find much information about the topic. I would suggest you to visit whe webpage http://www.msgtruth.org/cancer.htm . On the same page there are several links on the right side showing connections of MSG to **other diseases**.

Comment: Interesting sources. I was suspicious of msgtruth.org, but after inspecting it for a bit, it actually seems alright.

Comment: The same arguments can be said for table salt.